# Cloning form in a colorbox overlay

Tags: jquery, clone, colorbox

I am using colorbox overlay plugin........

At the bottom of the page I have a div with form containing text/check-box and submit button (there is also client side validation to check if the check-box is ticked as its mandatory). I am cloning the DIV into a color-box overlay...which works fine as I am using jquery clone method to display the contents in the overlay.

I issue is bcoz the content is cloned, if I select the check-box on the main page the overlay has the check-box ticked but if I tick/un-tick the check-box in the overlay the content on the main page remains unchanged, due to which the form is not getting submitted from the overlay.

Is there a way I can do the following...
Even if the check-box is ticked on the main page...the content in the overlay should not inherit the tick even though its cloned...so it behaves independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this is a JQuery question more than a ColorBox question.

Ensure the boolean **withDataAndEvents** is set to *False* when cloning. (Note that the default was *True* in Jquery 1.5.0 and was later revised to be *False*.)

Or am I missing something?